# (MiniZinc) unrecognized option `--solver'

Tags: command-line, minizinc

After resolving the problem I had with the PATH at [Unable to run MiniZinc from command line - Even after adding installation location to PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51984197/unable-to-run-minizinc-from-command-line-even-after-adding-installation-locati/51993574#51993574), I soon encountered another problem when invoking the solver via the command `minizinc -c --solver Gecode model.mzn data.dzn`. I obtained the error: `minizinc: unrecognized option "--solver"`.

How can I resolve this? I also want to use the CBC and Gurobi solvers (mzn-cbc, mzn-gurobi) as well..

I am following the instructions given at http://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.2.0/en/command_line.html if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--solver` option was introduced in the release today, version 2.2.0. Please install the newest version of MiniZinc and this should solve you problem

Comment: Thank you for the update! The upgraded version came at the right time :)